# Hit test along the Y axis from the device/camera location?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

My application involves a user pointing their phone like a remote—as opposed to an 'AR window'—at virtual nodes. (See illustration.) These nodes are manually placed in the environment and aren't anchored to a physical plane. They will be floating.

To do this, I would need to cast along the Y axis from the camera/screen center and test for any hits along that ray. In Unity, I would do this by doing a Raycast hit test from the camera's `transform.top`, but I'm not sure how to do this in SceneKit.

I have had success using `sceneView.hitTest` on the Z axis, but this isn't my ultimate use case. I have also tried using `scene.hitTestWithSegment()`, using the camera world space as the `from` but I'm not sure how to get the `to`. I'm guessing I would need to cast a ray along the local Y axis and get a point along it, which just leads me back to my original problem.

Any tips on where to look? Is there a similar convenience to casting from a local `transform.top` in SceneKit?

Thank you, in advance!

Illustration:

[image]

** **Update** **

Per Josh Homann's answer below, I wound up solving it like so:

```
// Set local segment end and convert to world space
let segmentLocalEnd:SCNVector3 = SCNVector3(0,20,0)
let segmentWorldEnd:SCNVector3 = sceneView.pointOfView!.convertPosition(segmentLocalEnd, to: nil)
// Get hits
let hitResults:[SCNHitTestResult] = scene.hitTestWithSegment(
    from: sceneView.pointOfView!.worldPosition,
    to: segmentWorldEnd,
    options: [SCNHitTestOption.firstFoundOnly.rawValue: true]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have most of the answer.  In an AR view you would project a ray from the camera along the look at vector.  In your case though you want to go perpendicular to the look at vector, so instead you just project a ray from the camera along the up vector (0,1,0) (assuming you haven't rotated your space and positive Y is up). In SceneKit you can't actually test along a infinite ray, so just pick a sufficiently large value and pass it into [`hitTestWithSegment(from:to:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407998-hittestwithsegment)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I'm trying a few iterations on that but still don't seem to be getting any hits. Starting with Z index, I tried `cameraNode.hitTestWithSegment(from: SCNVector3(0,0,0), to: SCNVector3(0,0,10))` where `cameraNode` is a local variable node placed where the camera is in world space. But I don't get any hits on my `SCNSphere` instances. I'm guessing I have a coordinate system issue?

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I did a little more digging and saw `hitTestWithSegment()` works within the calling node's local coordinate space, so I got the world `to:` by converting camera local (-10,0,0) using `convertPosition()`. One small puzzle: why would I need to use the X axis and not Y? I am holding the camera portrait and have my orientation set to Portrait only.

Comment: I think something was just wonky with how I was using the camera's position. I switched to using `sceneView.pointOfView` and the orientation came out as expected. Thanks, again for the help @Josh.